# I want to setup git alias to change a directory in windows

Tags: git

I have the following git aliases setup

```
[alias]
    history = log --all --graph --decorate --oneline
    project1 = "cd /c/projects/test1"
    project2 = "cd c:/projects/test2"
```

But on running `git project` I get this error

> Expansion of alias 'project1' failed; 'cd' is not a git command

[image]

I am trying this on a Windows 10 machine

Comment: Why are you setting this as a Git alias?

Comment: You could make this a normal alias?

Answer (score 1):

Aliases to commands that are not git commands should begin with '!' :

```
[alias]
    foo1 = "cd foo1"    # will expand to "git cd foo1"
    foo2 = "! cd foo2"  # will expand to "cd foo2"
```

---

@phd is correct : I only thought of non git commands, but `cd` is specific and needs to modify the environment *of the current shell*.

I don't see an easy way to turn `cd foo` into an alias.

You should look at how to create an alias or function for the shell(s) you use.

Comment: "*`foo2 = "! cd foo2"`  # will expand to "cd foo2"*" Are you sure? I think that's expanded to `sh -c "cd foo2"` and that's why this alias doesn't work — it changes the current directory for the subshell but not for the current `git` process, even less for the current shell in the terminal. I think the only way to change directory is shell alias or function — only they are executed in the context of the current shell and can change the current environment.

Answer (score 0):

Git aliases are useful for making aliases for long git commands,
like your history command.
However, for *non-git commands*, I wouldn't use git aliases.

The reason for the error you're getting is that your aliases are expanded to

```
git cd /c/projects/test1
git cd c:/projects/test2
```

But, `cd` is not a git command, what you want is

```
cd /c/projects/test1
cd c:/projects/test2
```

Since these commands are not related to git, I would pick another tool to do this.

From looking at your screenshot, it appears you are using Powershell.
You can use powershell functions to achieve that:

```
function project1 { cd /c/projects/test1 }
function project2 { cd c:/projects/test2 }
```

Put this in your powershell profile.ps1 file to make these functions available every time you launch powershell. More info [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_profiles?view=powershell-7).

Answer (score -1):

For Windows (tested on 7,10) you may try https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DOSKEY feature:

1. Put `macros.doskey` file to `C:\Users\%userprofile%\bin` with the following content

   ```
   mvnx=mvn clean install -s path\to\my\customsettings.xmlfile -T 2C
   ...
   ... all your other windows aliases
   ...
   ```
2. Open `cmd` and type the following information

   ```
   reg add "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Command Processor" /v Autorun /d "doskey /macrofile=\"%userprofile%\bin\macros.doskey\"" /f
   reg query "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Command Processor" /v Autorun
   ```
3. Restart Windows cmd
4. After that, once I'm type `mvnx` in Windows CMD it triggering the alias above.